# How to get a UK visa after a 10 year ban is over

Tags: visas, uk, visa-bans

I previously had a 10 year ban from the UK. How do I go about getting a visa now? My circumstances have changed. I am a permanent resident in USA and have a good job.

Comment: Exactly what do you need help with?

Comment: How long has passed since the ban, is the 10 years up?

Answer (score 9):

You apply for a visa in the usual way - start [here](https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration)

Note, however, that if UK immigration has seen fit to ban you then any application you make now will be treated with considerable skepticism and will attract considerable scrutiny. You have quite a high bar to reach.

You might do well to find a UK lawyer with experience in immigration cases such as yours and take their advice.